Trello Attachment By API
I am able to create a Trello card and send the attachment by API through VBA Access code. The attachment is PDF, and I am sending it by encoding(often base64), but sometimes, the attachment file does not open.
I can drag and drop almost any attachment from our computer screens without encoding, but the code requires encoding. I wonder if some experienced Trello power-up programmers who have overcome this issue can help me, please?
